# I very new at both html and php. This is my first time posting. Add state code dropdown list

Tags: php, dropdown

I have a standard form with all user info, I want to have a drop down list where the state input is so the user can select the state. I have a database with state code and description. Here's the code for my form, just need to know how to add the drop down list so it will show up where the state code is.  I've tried putting the drop down using the regular drop down code but when I do that the drop down list shows up at the top of the form.

```
<section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-warpper">
        <h2>Sign up</h2>
        <form class="signup-form" action="includes/signupinc.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="mbrnumber" placeholder="Member Number">
            <input type="text" name="alias" placeholder="Alias">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City">
            <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State">
            <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button = type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue with the drop down code showing at the top. Can you edit your post so I can see what you tried that did not work

Comment: Please show the code where the droptdown is messing up your UI

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with this and have come up with something like I want.  I would like the state code drop down list to look like the placeholder in the rest of the form. Width height I know I can style this but not sure just how to do that.  Here's the code I have come up with.  The state drop down list comes from my database.

```
<section class="main-container">
<div class="main-warpper">
<h2>Sign up</h2>
    <form class="signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="clubname" placeholder="Your databae name(lower case only no spaces)">
        <input type="text" name="mbrnumber" placeholder="Member Number">
        <input type="text" name="alias" placeholder="Alias">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City">
        <tr>
        <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State">
        <select name="state">
            <?php

            $sql="Select * from matchstates";
            echo "<option value='' selected>Select State</option>";
            foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) { 

                echo "<option value=$row[statecode]>$row[statename]</option>";

            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </tr>
        <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
        <button = type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</div>
```